# Android Sliding Menu from both left and right side

Tags: android, slidingmenu

In my android app i am using Sliding Menu  https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.The drawer should get open from both side.I am having a button at top-right corner of screen. By clicking that button the page should come from right to left but the page is coming from left to right. Here is my code

```
  

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_complaint_type);
             menuS = new SlidingMenu(this);
            menuS.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
            menuS.setMenu(R.layout.activity_settings);
            menuS.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.activity_settings1);
            menuS.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
            menuS.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
            //     menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
            menuS.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
            menuS.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
            menuS.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        }

           @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageButton_settings:
                menuS.toggle();
                     break;
                 default:
                     break;
                }
                }
```

Thanks for the help.